# How to fix "pattern-matching is not exhaustive",

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I want to write function that will add two elements of type eval

```
type eval = Num of float | Neg | Add | Sub | Mul | Div;;
```

OCaml compiler gives me this warning, but I do not know exactly what it wants. It works, but I want to make it without this warning.

```
# let (+++) (Num a) (Num b) =
  match (Num a), (Num b) with
  | (Add|Neg|Sub|Mul|Div), _ -> failwith "01"
  | _, (Add|Neg|Sub|Mul|Div) -> failwith "02"
  | _, _ -> Num (a +. b)
  ;;        
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(Neg|Add|Sub|Mul|Div)
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(Neg|Add|Sub|Mul|Div)
val ( +++ ) : eval -> eval -> eval = <fun>
```

Comment: Try calling your `+++` function with anything other than a `Num`. Your `failwith "01"` and `failwith "02"` cases will never be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-exhaustive patterns are here:

```
 let (+++) (Num a) (Num b) = ...
```

With those pattern, you are making the hypothesis that the argument of `+++` are always of the form `Num _` without enforcing it in the type system.
If you want to get rid of the warning you should expand the pattern matching to catch all other cases:

```
 let (+++) x y = match x, y with 
 | ...
```